# Show name of item in destroy confirmation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to make the confirmation of deletion more descriptive. However I cannot access the item name using a typical #{item.name}. How do I show the item name in the confirmation?

```
<%= link_to item, method: :delete,  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete [item name here]? This action cannot be undone.' } do %>
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Delete</button>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String interpolation (`#{...}`) only works in double-quoted strings. Look at this example:

```
'#{2 + 2}' => "\#{2 + 2}"
"#{2 + 2}" => "4"
```

Updated line:

```
<%= link_to item, method: :delete,
      data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete #{item.name}? This action cannot be undone." } do %>
```